# Acumos Web on-boading failed at dockerise step

Tags: acumos

I used oneclick_deploy.sh script to deploy acumos, and when I try to on-board a model by Web-onboarding it fails at dockerize step with the following message

"java.net.UnknownHostException: aio: Name or service not known"

Where "aio" was the hostname of the system on which I installed acumos. I changed my hostname by "acumos" but the error message remains the same.

Comment: Would you please share the log line where you found this error?

Comment: When I put my mouse on the red icon "Dockerise" this message and only this message appears

Answer (score 1):

I can help you. I am the developer of the AIO deploy toolset. Some initial questions to help me steer the debugging on the issue:

1) When did you clone the system-integration repo? Note I am improving the reliability of the process as more users adopt it, and you may be missing later bug fixes.

2) Did you deploy the AIO using docker or kubernetes? (the oneclick_deploy.sh script takes an optional parameter which selects docker or k8s, by default docker, as the platform under which the Acumos components are installed)

3) Can you check if /etc/hosts correctly contains a line for your hostname? This should be set for ACUMOS_DOMAIN in oneclick_deploy.sh (see procedure setup_prereqs). The issue you report indicates that one of the components cannot resolve the hostname "aio". This should not be an issue if you are using a recent version of the AIO toolset as I added explicit /etc/hosts mapping for the ACUMOS_DOMAIN value in the component templates (docker and k8s).

Let's start there. Glad that you are trying this out, and I'll help you get beyond this quickly.